# Can't get Plan or Plan.Name from Stripe.Net Invoice using Linq

Tags: asp.net, linq, stripe-payments

I need to use something like Linq to Select specific Invoice data coming from Stripe.Net. m.Description is null, so I need to get the Description from Plan.Name, which is contained here StripeInvoiceLineItems.Data.Plan.Name. Here is my code.

```
//Get Invoices
var invoices = StripeHelper.GetAllInvoices(merchant.StripeCustomerId);

var convertInvoices = invoices
                .Select(m => new Stripe.StripeInvoice
               {
                   Id = m.Id,
                   Description = m.StripeInvoiceLineItems.Data.Where(i => i.InvoiceId == m.Id).Select(i => i.Plan.Name).ToString(),
                   StripeInvoiceLineItems = m.StripeInvoiceLineItems,
                   Date = m.Date,
                   Paid = m.Paid,
                   Total = m.Subtotal,
                   NextPaymentAttempt = m.NextPaymentAttempt,

               })
               .ToList();
```

This doesn't work either.

```
m.StripeInvoiceLineItems.Data[0].Plan.Name
```

There is no error. I just don't get any data and I'm trying to get the Description of the Invoice using Plan.Name.

Any help is much appreciated Thanks!

Comment: Your problems is that Description is null?

Comment: @arslanlqbal Yes, the Description for the Invoice is null, so I need to get that from the Name of the Plan.

Comment: share the code for GetAllInvoices method

Comment: @ArslanIqbal The method is returning IEnumberable<Stripe.StripeInvoices>. Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `Where`:

```
Description = m.StripeInvoiceLineItems.Data
                                      .FirstOrDefault(i => i.InvoiceId == m.Id)
                                      .Plan.Name;
```

`Where` return type is `Queryable` and using `ToString()` on these types does not make sense.

Comment: Unfortunately, i.InvoiceId is Null, so I'm getting a null reference exception. I've been trying to work with Stripe Support as well, but they haven't been real helpful so far.

Comment: I finally got this to work. I was able to see that i.id and m.SubscriptionId were the same. Here is what I used. Description = m.StripeInvoiceLineItems.Data.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == m.SubscriptionId).Plan.Name,

Comment: Seems like the SubscriptionId is the only relationship that exists between the Invoice and StripeInvoiceLineItems.Data.